# ¿Cómo se pueden deconstruir las siguientes oraciones? How to deconstruct these sentences?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática

Un artículo publicado en The Four Hour Work Week blog by Tim Ferriss llamado [How to Learn (But Not Master) any Language in 1 Hour](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/11/07/how-to-learn-but-not-master-any-language-in-1-hour-plus-a-favor/) sugiere que la deconstrucción de un idioma es una de las cosas más importantes para aprenderlo. **Por lo tanto, mi pregunta es: ¿cuáles son las traducciones gramaticalmente correctas de las siguientes oraciones?**

An article from The Four Hour Work Week blog by Tim Ferriss called [How to Learn (But Not Master) any Language in 1 Hour](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/11/07/how-to-learn-but-not-master-any-language-in-1-hour-plus-a-favor/) suggests that deconstructing a language is one of the most important parts of learning it. The article lists several basic sentences to translate into the target language as a starting point. Obviously Google is not much help getting translations when literal accuracy is important.

**So, my question is: what are the grammatically correct translations for these sentences in Spanish?**

1. It is John’s apple.
2. I give John the apple.
3. We give him the apple.
4. He gives it to John.
5. She gives it to him.
6. I must give it to him.
7. I want to give it to her.
8. I don't give him the apple.
9. I gave him the apple.
10. I will give him the apple.

Also, it probably goes without saying, but if there are regional differences or ways of translating these sentences into different types of phrases, those aren't the translations I'm looking for. The point of this is to learn proper sentence structure, not to figure out "How a person would actually say xyz...".

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I really don't understand this question and the its meaning. If you translate word by word the words of the egs, you can construct it without having a clue about the grammar. Do you need a starting point? For eg, the answer of Juan Pablo its perfect, but doing this you wont find (for example) that in english you need repeat the subject for the first sentence (apple) with "it". I think (it's an opinion) that you must be a perfect english grammar studient to learning by this way.

Comment: La intención es que la deconstrucción de las frases me ayuda para entender cómo el español se estructuran de forma diferente que el Inglés. Para que cuando estoy aprendiendo, tengo un esquema (comprensión) del básicos de cómo las palabras deben usarse juntos........

The intention is that the deconstruction of the sentences helps me to understand how Spanish is structured differently than English. So that when I am learning, a have a basic schema (understanding) of how the words ought to be used together.

Comment: I think (just an opinion) that even eng and spa has a similar grammar structure, you can't do that. Is like if a native spanish speaker tries to learn deutsch or even latin. The grammar reflects the mind structure of the speaker so a comparition can be only for translation pourposes. There are a lot of things that you can't think at the same way that me, and there are a lot of thinks that I can't think at the same way that you think. But we can talk any thing on the world with both lang. For example, in latin there is a lot of verb conjugations that you can't even think on spanish or english.

Comment: If you want study the grammar of any language, I suggest you try to think in that language.

Comment: I was thinking about your pourposes and I think I can help you with an answer, I hope it helps you a little more.

Comment: This appears to be a simple translation request. Or well, ten of them. Simple translation is off-topic. If there are passages you are struggling to translate due to some nuance in the language, then it is appropriate to ask here--but you should ask one question for each passage, not a single question for ten. Please edit your question, or explain why it is helpful to keep all 10 translations as a single question, or this question will probably be closed.

Comment: Flimzy, it is not a simple translation request. I've explained that I am asking for instruction relating to proper grammar. If it were a simple translation request, I could simply type it into Google Translate or ask a Spanish speaking friend. I am hoping to get an answer from a bilingual person who knows both Spanish and English grammar well.

Comment: I think we all know better than to trust Google for simple translation work. That doesn't really make this on-topic. It seems almost as if you're asking "teach me Spanish." None of the 10 passages are particularly difficult to translate. I'm having a difficult time understanding why this is an on-topic or constructive question. I see it as either simple translation (which you deny, although I don't see any evidence how it's different), or far too broad, as asking someone to teach you Spanish.

Comment: For now I am going to close this question, although this needn't be a permanent fate for this question.  I invite you to discuss this on Meta, if you feel it needs additional attention, or simply get 5 re-open votes, which will indicate the community believes it's a good questions as it's written.

Comment: So, if this site isn't here to "teach people Spanish" or, help them further their knowledge of Spanish, what is it here for? I find it really rude that you're basically closing this question because of my lack of knowledge and desire to learn the basics. Questions on this level would never be closed in StackOverflow.

Comment: @JosiahSprague: Have you read our [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: @JosiahSprague: I just finished reading the article. Maybe if you rephrase the question in such a way as to ask for why things are like that in Spanish. For example in the first sentence: "Es la manzana de John"/"Es de John la manzana"/"Es de John"/"De John es la manzana". They are all valid translations and you can see that the order of subject, verb, and object could vary and still be valid. This can make the approach the author of the article follows a little challenging. Hope this helps to get your question reopened.

Comment: I have read the article, too, and it's an interesting read. However, I think it shows that this really isn't a useful way to ask the question. Those sentences are intended as diagnostic sentences--and for those purposes, this *is* just a translation question. It's also likely that google translate would be sufficient for the purposes the article talks about.

Comment: What I think would make for much more interesting and constructive questions would be, once you have the Spanish translation of the sentence (even from google translate), if you need help deconstructing the grammatical syntax, etc, then please, by all means, ask _those_ questions here.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, I have read the FAQ. I am looking for answers that are "supported by ... specific expertise". Which is exactly why Google Translate is not sufficient. The whole purpose of the deconstructed sentences is to not to know what they mean on the level of basic translation, but to understand the right way of conveying the simple, yet specific, meanings contained therein using Spanish. In some cases, there may be more than one way of saying it. Just like you can say "The apple is red." or "It is a red apple." in English, but I am looking for a semantically equivalent translation.

Comment: @JosiahSprague: Please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1792/la-tertulia), or open a question on [meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/) if you would like to discuss this further.  Comments are not a constructive means of discussing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

After we talk on the comments, I will try with a correct grammar "translation". Take care that in spanish the "elipsis" is very often, so they can be sound bad, but are correct on their grammar.

> 1: It is John’s apple.

It: esta / is: es / Jonh's: de John. / Apple: Manzana.

Esta es de John, la manzana. (Usual way to say it: Esta es la manzana de John.)

> 2: I give John the apple.

I: yo / give: doy / Jonh: a John. / Apple: Manzana.

More accurate and grammar to say it: Yo dí a John la manzana.
Usual way to say it: Yo le [a John] dí a John una manzana.

> 3: We give him the apple.

Nosotros damos a él una manzana. (Nosotros le damos una manzana)

> 4: He gives it to John.
>   Él lo dió a John.
>
> 5: She gives it to him.

Ella se lo da. (to him: se, because there is a it, you can't use "Ella le lo da")

> 6: I must give it to him.

Yo debo dárselo. Idem: dar + se + lo. This happens because the verb is in infinitive, the "must" carries the conjugation.

> 7: I want to give it to her.

Yo quiero dárselo. Idem to 6. Le (se) works for masculine / femenine. The it is masculine because is neutral.

> 8: I don't give him the apple.

Yo no quiero darle la manzana. Common "le" because the "Complemento Directo" is the noun, not the pronoun.

> 9: I gave him the apple.

Yo le doy la manzana. Idem

> 10: I will give him the apple.

Yo le daré la manzana.

If you are doing your homework about OD and OI on spanish, please ask for the grammar and Ill be glad to answer you.

Take care when you use a pronoun verb (dárselo) you must respect the accent rule for the ticks:

da: it's ok, doesn't carry the "tick" (tilde)

dalo: it's ok.

dáselo: must carry the tick.

Answer (score 1):

No leí el artículo, pero en cualquier caso, estas son las traducciones que me suenan más naturales, manteniendo la mayor fidelidad posible a la estructra gramatical de las originales. En muchos casos, los pronombres como él, ella, etc, podrían obviarse (y en la práctica se obviarían) si se sobrentendieran por el contexto.

> It is John’s apple.
>
> Es la manzana de John.
>
> I give John the apple.
>
> Le doy la manzana a John (also: Le doy a John la manzana)
>
> We give him the apple.
>
> Le damos la manzana (a él)
>
> He gives it to John.
>
> Él se la da a John.
>
> She gives it to him.
>
> Ella se la da a él.
>
> I must give it to him.
>
> Debo dársela a él (also: Tengo que dársela a él).
>
> I want to give it to her.
>
> Quiero dársela a ella.
>
> I don't give him the apple.
>
> No le doy la manzana (a él).
>
> I gave him the apple.
>
> Le di la manzana (a él).
>
> I will give him the apple.
>
> Le daré la manzana (also: le voy a dar la manzana).

Comment: Gracias! Tengo que estudiarlo para ver si eso es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: Be aware adding and/or remove not useful grammar words, the OP ask for a grammar comparision.